# Funds cannot be sent to accounts located in BR because its outside of your platform region

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have the following app:

Users can set up e-commerce stores. Buyers can add items from multiple stores to their checkout. For example, buyer 1 goes to store A and adds a $10 book to his basket. He then goes to store B and adds a $15 bag to his basket.

At checkout, when buyer 1 pays $20 in total. I want to be able to transfer $15 to store B and $10 to store A. I thought I accomplished this successfully with the following code:

**Checkout**

```
await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount,
    currency,
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    receipt_email,
});
```

**Payment**

```
await stripe.transfers.create({
    amount,
    currency,
    destination,
    source_transaction,
})
```

However, I realised today in livemode that I can not transfer funds from my balance to a user because they are in Brazil and my platform account is in the UK. I talked to support, and the options they outlined to me are:

1. Setup platform account in Brazil
2. Use direct charges (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges)
3. Use settlement merchants (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#settlement-merchant)

Currently, 1 is out of the question. Since I can't set up the legal information for each non-SEPA region at this time.
Can someone provide some guidance on how to collect direct charges and split the payout to multiple accounts? Similar to the example above

Comment: Stripe's separate charges and transfers flow does sound like what you want to use if you want to create a single PaymentIntent and transfer funds to more than one connected account.The transfer from UK to BR won't be possible with this charge type. Also, cross border transfers are only allowed for US platforms: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/cross-border-payouts

If you go with direct charges, you'll have to create two PaymentIntents (one for store A, one for store B). Funds received through direct charges can only be transferred to the connected account used for the charge.

Comment: Sadly, this seems like the only way for now.